# display selected attributes in my custom tab while creating configurable product magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to do two tasks with configurable product, 1. I want to add description to each selected attribute for the product, 2. I want to save price for a group of selection (not individually as it does by default). So for the task first I want to display all attributes in .phtml file, can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my first task(How to add description to each selected attribute for the product). For performing this task, you need to create attributes(like: size, paper) of type text area and add to these  attributes to any attribute set(for ex : "News Paper"). Now create a new configurable product with "News Paper", you will see all description field there.